# Basemap - Attribute (python)

Tags: python, attributeerror, matplotlib-basemap

I am relatively new to programming.

I'm trying to run the following:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

my_map = Basemap(projection = 'ortho', lat_0=50, lon_0=-100,
                resolution = 'l', area_thresh=1000.0)

my_map.drawcoastlines()
my_map.drawcountries()
my_map.fillcontinents(color='red')

plt.show()
```

However, I get "AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_axis_bgcolor'"

I'm using python 3.6, matplotlib 2.2.0, basemap 1.0.7.  They were downloaded using Anaconda.

OS - Mac 10.12.4

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2):

The matplotlib deprecated the get_axis_bgcolor. You'll need to update basemap to version 1.1.0 to fix this error. It's installable via conda-forge, via:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
```

In case you'll get error like, "Unable to open boundary dataset file. Only the 'crude' and  'low', resolution datasets are installed by default." Install, the additional files via:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@user45237841](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8861059/user45237841)'s answer, you can also change the `resolution` to `c` or `l` to resolve this error `Unable to open boundary dataset file. Only the 'crude' and 'low', resolution datasets are installed by default.`

```
my_map = Basemap(projection = 'ortho', lat_0=50, lon_0=-100,
            resolution = 'c', area_thresh=1000.0)  
# c is for crude and l is for low
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Jupyter-notebook make sure that using --yes to processing package installing on platform. `conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires --yes`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to update just replace `get_axis_bgcolor` with `get_facecolor` in `\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py` file.

```
Line 1623:         fill_color = ax.get_facecolor()
Line 1767:         axisbgc = ax.get_facecolor()
```